# Ошибки при чтении, записи потоками общих массивов

Tags: массивы, delphi, потоки-данных, многопоточность

Допустим есть 4-ре потока, которые читают (только читают) данные из одного массива и записывают (только записывают) в другой массив. Все 4-ре потока работают с одной и той же парой массивов. Будут ли возникать между потоками какие-либо ошибки при чтении, записи общих массивов?

Comment: Ошибки врятли, а вот то что результат будет непредсказуемым это точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если так сделать, что бы области их записи и чтения не пересекались (то есть, первый поток пишет/читает только по адресам 0..99, второй - по адресам 100..199, четвертый - 200..299), то никаких проблем.
Если есть области, по которым только читают и не пишут, то их можно безопасно читать с разных тредов.

Во всех остальных случаях нужна синхронизация, например критическая секция.